# Wordpress Menu options in the Admin: Posts for the dropdowns

Tags: posts, menus

Under Appearance > Menus

I seem to be able to add Categories, Pages, or Custom Links as my menu/sub-menu dropdown items...but I can't add posts.

I would like to have posts in my dropdown (posts of a given category), but I can't seem to do this without writing custom links, which is going to be time-consuming.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Screen Options dropdown tab at the top right on the menus page. There's a checkbox there to enable posts and more.

Cheers,
CW

Comment: Thanks...would not have figured that out (thought that only controlled the dashboard at the top!)